# Apache POI HWPF - problem in convert doc file to pdf

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, hwpf

I am currently working Java project with use of apache poi.
Now in my project I want to convert doc file to pdf file. The conversion done successfully but I only get text in pdf not any text style or text colour.
My pdf file looks like a black & white. While my doc file is coloured and have different style of text.

This is my code,

```
 POIFSFileSystem fs = null;  
 Document document = new Document(); 

 try {  
     System.out.println("Starting the test");  
     fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream("/document/test2.doc"));  

     HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  
     WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);  

     OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("/document/test.pdf")); 

     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);  

     Range range = doc.getRange();
     document.open();  
     writer.setPageEmpty(true);  
     document.newPage();  
     writer.setPageEmpty(true);  

     String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();  
     for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {  

         org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph pr = range.getParagraph(i);
        // CharacterRun run = pr.getCharacterRun(i);
        // run.setBold(true);
        // run.setCapitalized(true);
        // run.setItalic(true);
         paragraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].replaceAll("\\cM?\r?\n", "");  
     System.out.println("Length:" + paragraphs[i].length());  
     System.out.println("Paragraph" + i + ": " + paragraphs[i].toString());  

     // add the paragraph to the document  
     document.add(new Paragraph(paragraphs[i]));  
     }  

     System.out.println("Document testing completed");  
 } catch (Exception e) {  
     System.out.println("Exception during test");  
     e.printStackTrace();  
 } finally {  
                 // close the document  
    document.close();  
             }  
 }
```

please help me.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at Apache Tika, there's a good example of reading some style information from a HWPF document. The code in Tika generates HTML based on the HWPF contents, but you should find that something very similar works for your case.

The Tika class is 
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-parsers/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/microsoft/WordExtractor.java

One thing to note about word documents is that everything in any one Character Run has the same formatting applied to it. A Paragraph is therefore made up of one or more Character Runs. Some styling is applied to a Paragraph, and other parts are done on the runs. Depending on what formatting interests you, it may therefore be on the paragraph or the run.

Answer (score 4):

If you use WordExtractor, you will get text only. Try using `CharacterRun` class. You will get style along with text. Please refer following Sample code.

```
Range range = doc.getRange();
for (int i = 0; i < range.numParagraphs(); i++) {
    org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph poiPara = range.getParagraph(i);
    int j = 0;
    while (true) {
        CharacterRun run = poiPara.getCharacterRun(j++);
        System.out.println("Color "+run.getColor());
        System.out.println("Font size "+run.getFontSize());
        System.out.println("Font Name "+run.getFontName());
        System.out.println(run.isBold()+" "+run.isItalic()+" "+run.getUnderlineCode());
        System.out.println("Text is "+run.text());
        if (run.getEndOffset() == poiPara.getEndOffset()) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```