# How to open/show .doc,.docx,xls,ppt file in Android Using Apache POI

Tags: android, apache-poi, android-view

I am working on Document fetch App and i need to show/open selected document such as .doc,.docx,ppt,xls from cloud storage(google drive).
i am new ain Android and not getting how to use this.

Comment: Aahh..Quit long time ago I had to manage it, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352116/apache-poi-hwpf-problem-in-convert-doc-file-to-pdf

Comment: can you please share full working code i need urgent.

Comment: their is no code the link you suggested

Comment: Just checkout from https://code.google.com/p/display-msoffice-docs-android-with-apache-poi/source/checkout

Comment: Not working for me..need some urgent help